# Jquery click event fire twice on modal form

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, events, modal-dialog

I have a Jquery modal form create via ajax with a form, in this form I insert a button for cloning a select with checking for copy.
When I use it the first time it's work perfectly but if I call modal the second time the click event fire twice.
The modal and the click declaration is in ajax file called

this is the click declaration with control function

```
$("#addfonte").unbind("click");
    $("#addfonte").off("click");
    $(document).on("click","#addfonte",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var current = $("#IdAddFonte").val();
        var index = $(".newfonte").length + 1;
        console.log("indice"+index);    
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var select = $('.newfonte option:selected');
        var presente=false;
        console.log("quante ne ho "+select.length);

        //Clone the DropDownList
        var ddl = $("#IdAddFonte").clone();

        //Set the ID and Name
        var newname="AddFonte_"+index;
        var newbutton="DelButton_"+index;
        ddl.attr("id", newname);
        ddl.attr("name", newname);
        ddl.attr("class","newfonte");

        //[OPTIONAL] Copy the selected value
        var selectedValue = $("#IdAddFonte option:selected").val();
        ddl.find("option[value = '" + selectedValue + "']").attr("selected", "selected");

        select.each(function(){
            var sameid="#"+$(this).parent().attr('id');
            console.log("stesso id "+sameid+" valore "+$(this).val()+" riferimento "+ddl.attr("id"))
            $(sameid).removeClass("evidenziato");
            $('#error').html("").removeClass("error");
            if ($(this).val()==current){
                    presente = true;
                    $('#error').html("Fonte già presente").addClass("error");
                    $(sameid).addClass("evidenziato");
                }
        });

        if (!presente){                      
            //Append to the DIV.
            $("#fonti").prepend(ddl);
            //$("#fonti").prepend("<br /><br />");
            var select = $('.newfonte option:selected');
            var valori="";
            $("#fonti .btdel").remove();
            select.each(function(index){
                selected=$(this).parent();

                //Set the ID and Name
                var newname="AddFonte_"+index;

                selected.attr("id", newname);
                selected.attr("name", newname);
                selected.attr("class","newfonte");
                var newbutton="DelButton_"+index;
                var bottone='<button id="';
                bottone+=newbutton+'" class="btdel">';
                bottone+='<img height="20px" src="images/Delete_Icon.png" alt="cancella fonte"></button>';
                $("#"+newname).after(bottone);
            });
            elencofonti(select);
            $(document).unbind("click","#fonti .btdel");
            $(document).on("click","#fonti .btdel",function(e){
                var select = $('.newfonte option:selected');
                e.preventDefault();     
                $(this).prev().remove();
                $(this).remove();
                elencofonti(select);
            });

        }
```

this the modal declaration

```
var dialog,form;
dialog =$('#ModalB').dialog({
    width: "auto",

    modal:true,
    title:"Inserisci anno di riferimento",
    open:function(){
        $('input:submit').hide();
        setTimeout(function(){$('#IdFunzione').focus();},50);
        originalContent = $("#ModalFormB").html();
    },
    close:function(dialog){
        console.log("chiusa la form");
         $("#ModalFormB").html(originalContent);
    },
    buttons:{
        <?php if ($dati){?>
        "Modifica":function(){
            $(this).dialog("close");
            ModificaImpianto();
            $("#ModalFormB").remove();
            $(this).dialog("destroy");
            //creaquestionario(idimpianto,idanagrafica,idutente,$('#ModalAnno').val());
            //dialog.find( "form" ).submit();

        },
        <?php }else{?>
            "Aggiungi":function(){
            $(this).dialog("close");
            AggiungiImpianto();
            $("#ModalFormB").remove();
            $(this).dialog("destroy");
            //creaquestionario(idimpianto,idanagrafica,idutente,$('#ModalAnno').val());
            //dialog.find( "form" ).submit();

        },<?php } ?>
        "Annulla": function() {
            $("#ModalFormB").remove();
            dialog.dialog( "close" );
            $(this).dialog("destroy");

        }   
    }
}).css("font-size", "0.7em");
form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      dialog.dialog( "close" );
      alert($("#ModalFormB").serialize());
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't assign click handlers inside click handlers. Move this outside: 
`$(document).on("click","#fonti .btdel",function(e){`

Comment: this click event work is the main click event when i open the dialog and click on button that exec the click function of before stantement and memorize the element.
I wnat to find a metod for reset the click method for #addfonte when I open the modal form like a recarge of page....